# problem with gmap valid key

Tags: google-maps

My google map works on local host perfect, but when i get key from codes.google for my server ip my google map alerts your browser does not support google map 
i dont know what is my problem can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not solved yet but i think that it is important to say that when download java script from google from address
http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=ABQIAAAAmfxEy26bISZt8fzqRClItBRc5N-P1NpY03Egq3jSesNMkYFHpRQxlBgZQE1fKa5udtRsjyL77M61mw
GValidateKey("") is in java script but i find in the web that it contains a key

Comment: when i try this link one more time GValidateKey contains a key, It make me suprised becouse i try it many times

Comment: I test it one another time the and i was suprised becouse when i add this link to a page and click on that link it works but when I test it directly from url bar of firefox it not work

Answer (score 1):

Try to get a the key for the full domain name (including subdomain), not the IP address.

Comment: i am trying to access my application server just from my ip

Answer (score 1):

You can't use your ip address to get an API key.

Also, you don't need to use your full domain name.  If you get an API key for 'example.com' - all of the sub-domains and directories on example.com will also be valid.